# How to clear the uploads in vaadin upload?

Tags: vaadin, polymer-1.0

I want to clear the previous uploads when I am re-routing to the vaadin upload component to again load other images. But whenever I click on the component it also show me the data for initial uploads:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For vaadin V23 its:

```
//Upload upload = new Upload();
upload.clearFileList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have looked through the code of vaadin-upload.html, there does not seem to a method, let alone a part of its API, that allows you to clear previously uploaded files. I needed this functionality in my project, so I modified vaadin-upload.html myself.

Inside the object passed to the `Polymer()` function in vaadin-upload.html, I added the following lines:

```
clearFiles: function() {
    this.set('files', []);
}
```

You can then use your favorite selector function to get an instance of `<vaadin-upload>` and then call `clearFiles()`. In the Polymer framework, this could look like:

```
this.$.myVaadinUpload.clearFiles();
```

Modifying a third party library is not ideal, but this work around is simple and clean.

Note that it is important to use `this.set()` (instead of `this.files = []`) to trigger Polymer's binding observers.

Answer (score 0):

With this html:

```
<vaadin-upload id="uploader" files="{{files}}"> ... </vaadin-upload>
```

you can just do the following in any of your element methods:

```
this.$.uploader.files = [];
```

This is cleaner since it does not require modifying the code of `vaadin-upload`.